# How to create a multidimensional array with values from dynamically created form fields, using jquery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, each, array-push

I have a form where I dynamicly add three fields at time.

Those fields each have diffrent class names.

I want to create a multidimensional array that stores the values of those fields.

The array needs to look like this:

```
var working_days = {
        0: {
            'workday': data,
            'from': data,
            'till': data
        },
        1: {
            'workday': data,
            'from': data,
            'till': data
        },
        2: {
            'workday': data,
            'from': data,
            'till': data
        },
        //etc.
    };
```

Prehaps using array push?

This is the code I have so far:

```
$('body').on('click','.createItem', function() {
    var working_days = {}

    console.log(values);
    $('input.startTime').each(function() {
        var startTime = $(this).val();
    });

    $('input.endTime').each(function() {
        var endTime = $(this).val();
    });

    $('select.day').each(function() {
        var day = $(this).val();
    });

});
```

What are possible ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery helper function `.serializeArray()` could be a good starting point for you. The resulting array of objects then needs to be transformed into your required format, using `.reduce()`. Here is a little fiddle to demonstrate a possible solution:

```js
const names={startTime:"from",endTime:"till"};
function addTimes(tblsel){
 $(tblsel).append($("#timegrp").html()) 
}
for (let n=6;n--;) addTimes("#times table");
$("#times").on("click",".rmv",function(){this.closest("tr").remove()});
$("#add").click(ev=>addTimes("#times table"));
$("#chk").click(ev=>{
  const res=$("#times").serializeArray().reduce((a,e)=>{
    if (e.name=="day") a.push({workday:e.value});
    else names[e.name] && (a[a.length-1][names[e.name]]=e.value);
    return a;
  },[]);
  console.log(res);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">add workday</button>
<button id="chk">check times</button>
<form id="times">
<table></table>
</form>

<template id="timegrp">
<tr><td><select name="day"><option>Monday</option>
<option>Tuesday</option>
<option>Wednesday</option>
<option>Thursday</option>
<option>Friday</option>
<option>Saturday</option>
<option>Sunday</option></select></td>
<td><input type="time" name="startTime" value="08:30"></td>
<td><input type="time" name="endTime" value="17:00"></td>
<td class="rmv" title="remove">&#x2718;<td></tr>
</template>
```

( My script creates an *array* of objects. The result as you requested it in your question was an *object*, not an array. )